# Network Unity не удаётся поднять сетевую игру

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я написал минимальную игру на Unity и хочу, чтобы со мной мог играть и мой друг с  своего компьютера. Но когда он пытается подключится к серверу, у него ничего не выходит.

Почему так получается, и что нужно сделать, чтобы к серверу могли подключатся с других компьютеров?

Comment: Нужно показать код, хотя бы.

Comment: Я не писал скриптов для подключения по сети, использовал Network Manager, тому и показывать нечего, может там что то в настройках сменить нужно, я искал ответ в интернете, но так и нечего не нашел(

Comment: Скачай сначала готовый проект от Unity с AssetStore и проверь, если он не будет работать у друга, то проблема не в проекте.

Comment: ваши компьютеры в одной локальной сети или нет? если нет, то даже с правильным кодом придется: 1 понять как устроены и работают сети. 2. Найти и попробовать разные способы соединения. 3. выбрать наиболее подходящий.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я помню нужно зайти в свой акк юнити и создать проект во вкладке multiplayer. Дальше подключатся через enable match maker.